# Difference between ptr++ and ptr + 1

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion, segmentation-fault

I wrote a code to reverse a string using recursion. When I run it, I get a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _print_rev_recursion(char *s);

int main() {

    _print_rev_recursion("string reversal");

    return (0);

}

void _print_rev_recursion(char *s)

{

    if (!*s)

        return; 

    _print_rev_recursion(s++);

    putchar(*s);

}
```

When I changed s++ to s + 1, the code works.
I thought both s++ and s+1 mean the same thing. I need clarification please.

This is the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _print_rev_recursion(char *s);

int main() {

    _print_rev_recursion("string reversal");

    return (0);

}

void _print_rev_recursion(char *s)

{

    if (!*s)

        return; 

    _print_rev_recursion(s + 1);

    putchar(*s);

}
```

Comment: _"I thought both s++ and s+1 mean the same thing"_ - They do not.  `s++` changes `s` while `s+1` does not. The values of the expressions are also different. `s++` has the value of `s` prior to the increment. `s+1` has the value of `s + 1`.

Comment: OT: `return` is not a function. Use `return 0;` instead. Use parentheses only if they add clarity to the code.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought both s++ and s+1 mean the same thing

They do not.

`s++` changes `s` while `s+1` does not.

The values of the expressions are also different. `s++` has the value of `s` prior to the increment. `s+1` has the value of `s + 1`.

Comment: It's all clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of `s++` the increment happens *after* the function is called, so you get infinite recursion. `s+1` makes the increment happen before the recursive call.

Comment: Actually, `++s` would change this instance of  `s` ahead of the `putchar()`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand better now

Comment: @Fe2O3 Well yes, good point. It would mess up the output.

Comment: Mess up? Sure would! Captain Kirk would "oldly" go where... `:-)` (Except that he'd be doing it in reverse considering the purpose of this code...)